# Dplyr, join successive dataframes to pre-existing columns, summing their values

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to perform multiple joins to original dataframe, from the same source with different IDs each time. Specifically I actually only need to do two joins, but when I perform the second join, the columns being joined already exist in the input df, and rather than add these columns with new names using the .x/.y suffixes, I want to sum the values to the existing columns. See the code below for the desired output.

```
# Input data:
values <- tibble(
  id = LETTERS[1:10],
  variable1 = 1:10,
  variable2 = (1:10)*10
)
df <- tibble(
  twin_id = c("A/F", "B/G", "C/H", "D/I", "E/J")
)
```

```
> values
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   id    variable1 variable2
   <chr>     <int>     <dbl>
 1 A             1        10
 2 B             2        20
 3 C             3        30
 4 D             4        40
 5 E             5        50
 6 F             6        60
 7 G             7        70
 8 H             8        80
 9 I             9        90
10 J            10       100
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  twin_id
  <chr>  
1 A/F    
2 B/G    
3 C/H    
4 D/I    
5 E/J
```

So this is the two joins:

```
joined_df <- df %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = twin_id, into = c("left_id", "right_id"), sep = "/", remove = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(values, by = c("left_id" = "id")) %>%
  left_join(values, by = c("right_id" = "id"))

> joined_df
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  twin_id left_id right_id variable1.x variable2.x variable1.y variable2.y
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>          <int>       <dbl>       <int>       <dbl>
1 A/F     A       F                  1          10           6          60
2 B/G     B       G                  2          20           7          70
3 C/H     C       H                  3          30           8          80
4 D/I     D       I                  4          40           9          90
5 E/J     E       J                  5          50          10         100
```

And this is the output I want, using the only way I can see to get it:

```
output_df_wanted <- joined_df %>%
  mutate(
    variable1 = variable1.x + variable1.y,
    variable2 = variable2.x + variable2.y) %>%
  select(twin_id, left_id, right_id, variable1, variable2)

> output_df_wanted
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  twin_id left_id right_id variable1 variable2
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <int>     <dbl>
1 A/F     A       F                7        70
2 B/G     B       G                9        90
3 C/H     C       H               11       110
4 D/I     D       I               13       130
5 E/J     E       J               15       150
```

I can see how to get what I want using a mutate statement, but I will have a much larger number of variables in the actually dataset. I am wondering if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: If your dataset is larger but you're still only doing a pair of ids (as in `twin_id`), then I think this is the most reasonable way to go.

Comment: You might be able to use `dplyr-1.0.0`'s `across` in a `mutate` to be able to simplify your `variable1`, `variable2`, ... logic, but I don't have 1.0.0 installed yet and don't want to speculate without testing.

Comment: The dataset in question will be like in twin_id (2 IDS) but there will be 6 variables. It's just about small enough where I can do it now by just typing out 6 mutate statements, but I was interested as I couldn't find anything in my searches about it. 

It might not be the best way to treat this kind of thing, but the real world has some messy datasets sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try reshaping your data and using `dplyr::summarise_at`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate(col = twin_id, into = c("left_id", "right_id"), sep = "/", remove = FALSE) %>%
  pivot_longer(-twin_id) %>% 
  left_join(values, by = c("value" = "id")) %>% 
  group_by(twin_id) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("variable")), sum) %>% 
  separate(col = twin_id, into = c("left_id", "right_id"), sep = "/", remove = FALSE)
## A tibble: 5 x 5
#  twin_id left_id right_id variable1 variable2
#  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <int>     <dbl>
#1 A/F     A       F                7        70
#2 B/G     B       G                9        90
#3 C/H     C       H               11       110
#4 D/I     D       I               13       130
#5 E/J     E       J               15       150
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my package *safejoin* if it's acceptable to you to use a github package.

The idea is that you have conflicting columns, *dplyr* and base R deal with conflict by renaming them while *safejoin* is more flexible, you can use the function you want to apply in case of conflicts. Here you want to add them so we'll use `` conflict = `+` ``, for the same effect you could have used `conflict = ~ .x + .y` or `conflict = ~ ..1 + ..2`.

```r
# remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(tidyverse)
library(safejoin)
values <- tibble(
  id = LETTERS[1:10],
  variable1 = 1:10,
  variable2 = (1:10)*10
)

df <- tibble(
  twin_id = c("A/F", "B/G", "C/H", "D/I", "E/J")
)

joined_df <- df %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = twin_id, into = c("left_id", "right_id"), sep = "/", remove = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(values, by = c("left_id" = "id")) %>%
  safe_left_join(values, by = c("right_id" = "id"), conflict = `+`)

joined_df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   twin_id left_id right_id variable1 variable2
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 A/F     A       F                7        70
#> 2 B/G     B       G                9        90
#> 3 C/H     C       H               11       110
#> 4 D/I     D       I               13       130
#> 5 E/J     E       J               15       150
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>